# Logging data in Azure Application Insights for a bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-application-insights

I managed to connect my bot's telemetry with Azure Application Insights. I am now trying to make it so the Application Insights can show certain values from the bot (example: a user's input). I assume this would be related to custom events, but after looking at documentations, I am still really confused and do not know how to set it up to log the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot framework itself has a way to write telemetry to an Application Insights instance. I believe this is what you've configured and have working so far. For writing custom events/metrics you would want to simply utilize the AI `TelemetryClient` yourself [like you would in any other .NET Core application](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Application-Insights-for-ASP.NET-Core).

Once registered, you would change your `IBot` class to take `TelemetryClient` as a dependency to its constructor which will then be injected for you and then you just start recording events/metrics as you normally would.

The real question I always like to ask is: do you *really* want to tightly couple yourself directly to the Application Insights APIs? Do you perhaps just want to have a certain level of logging that you're doing through the logging abstraction (e.g. `ILogger[<T>]`)? Or, if you need events, perhaps you want to use an `EventSource` instead. Both of these abstractions can then be captured by Application Insights by configuring [the appropriate telemetry modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging), but they do not tie your code directly to Application Insights itself. I believe the only thing that doesn't have a good existing abstraction would be if you needed to gather metrics. You could of course still build your own abstraction for that and then a custom module that funnels the details into AI.

Comment: So the suggestion would be to do our custom logging like in any other .net core app?We'd need to implement the nice things that the bot would log by itself if we used the App Insights TelemetryClient