# Where are the Logger logs stored in azure chatbot?

Tags: azure, logging, botframework, bots, chatbot

I'm practicing chatbot development using Microsoft core-bot sample:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Bots/DialogBot.cs

In this C# file, at line 45 they used a method called Logger.LogInformation? Can I use this method to write custom logs in my code? Also where are these logs stored, how can I check them during bot execution on local machine?

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy this bot to Azure App Service, you can enable log / route them to Application Insights. The provided sample, as far as I can see it's not saving it anywhere.

More info:

[Logging data in Azure Application Insights for a bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54915669/logging-data-in-azure-application-insights-for-a-bot)

[Azure Bot logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482779/azure-bot-logging)

Comment: Thank you for your response. As of now I'm developing on my local machine. I'm testing bot using bot framework emulator installed on my local machine. Is there any way to write logs and verify them during execution via bot framework emulator?

Comment: I don't think so